# How to export MySQL schema with data?

Tags: mysql

I have a complete schema with many tables with data in them in MySQL query browser. Now I want to send this complete database with all the tables/data to my colleague. How can I send this to my colleague, so that he can then place this complete schema in his MySQL Query browser?

Thanks.

Comment: The query browser only lets you query data, and not dump data from mysql. Use a different ( eg. toad ) tool for that

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I`m not sure where are you working, you could export it to file, and send it to your friend.
(root is my localhost username)

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases DB_NAME >databasename.sql
```

PS: mysqldump is actually a executable file present in your /MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

for example [ on windows ]

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe
```

or [ on linux ]

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump
```

Comment: I exported a schema on mysql workbench and got a .sql file. Can it be read in java?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) command.

If you are using MySQL Workbench open the server administration tab and you can do an [Export To Disk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-export-to-disk.html) from there using a GUI interface.

There are options to dump to a single file or directory, and whether to include data or not.

Answer (score 1):

you could export the database as a *.sql file using phpMyAdmin.

or write a C++/C#/Java etc Programm that generates such statements too.

http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php

I am no way affiliated with turtlemeat

Comment: write a program? Uh... why? Such a thing already exists: mysqldump