# Deploying a Java Web project to a physical server

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, intellij-idea

I've been developing a Java Web Project in IntelliJ IDEA - it consists of a few Java classes for logic, a few JSP files for the web-based UI, and uses a MySQL database - all hosted on my own computer (MySQL server for the database, and Apache Tomcat 9 for the web app).

How would I export this project, including the database, so I can set up a dedicated machine (say a desktop running Ubuntu Server or Debian, or even a Raspberry Pi, perhaps) to run it?

I've done some research on this, and what I've found is that I need to export a WAR file, but I can't seem to find that option in IntelliJ - all the guides I found were focused on Eclipse. I also have no idea what to do about the database.

Comment: for IntelliJ .war file see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562829/where-is-the-war-file-built-in-intellij-idea-located and for MySQL have a look in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566735/how-to-export-mysql-schema-with-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup dedicated machine for your application, you need to install web server(ex. Tomcat) and MySQL server on a machine.

Make sure that, when you are creating database connection in your WEB application, the MySQL server details should not be hardcoded. I would suggest you to use properties file to store Database details and use them for database connections.
Ex.database.properties

```
mks.dynamicPool.config=\
url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[yourmachinehost]:[SQL Server port]/[yourdatabase name];useCursors=true,\
driver=mks.frame.sql.jdbc.mssql.Driver,\
initialCapacity=5,\
maxCapacity=100,\
testTable=VersionIdentity
mks.dbUser=user1
mks.dbPassword=user1
```

1. To create war file of you application follow the steps :

   1. Click on Edit Configurations.
   2. Click on Deployment and add your artifact.
   3. Apply these changes.
   4. You can see a Build Artifacts under Build.
   5. Click on Build Artifacts and it will create a war/jar to the respective folder.
2. To deploy your application into tomcat server,

   - Copy/Extract your war file into [TomcatInstallDir]/webapps
3. To import and export your database:

   I hope you have set MYSQL Server into your path.(if not then set using command: set path=c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin)

   i. To export database, following command can be used:

   ```
   mysqldump -u YourUser -p YourDatabaseName > dumpfilename.sql

   Note: This command should prompt you for password and with correct password it would export the database.
   ```

   ii. To restore/import above exported database use following command:

   ```
   mysql -u YourUser -p YourDatabaseName < dumpfilename.sql
   ```
4. Update your database.properties file with your new Database details and start the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

Install on your dedicated server MySQL and Tomcat.
Import your database into sql script and export it into dedicated server.

After that use some build automation tools, **maven** or **gradle** for example to build **war** package and deploy it (copy to ../tomcat/webapp directory)

Do you use some web-based framework?

Comment: I am not using any special frameworks - all of my front-end is some (very messily coded, I might add) JSP files, and the rest is just Java classes, and a couple of external libraries (such as the MySQL connector and JavaMail).

Comment: then just copy all project files you have into ../tomcat/webapps/firstwebapp/*